# code coverage report for multimodule project through maven and clover

Tags: maven, code-coverage, clover

I am working on multimodule project, and my project include 7 modules . I am using clover to create aggregate report but first thing is that clover.db is creating for every module. And second thing is that it works fine when i use command like:

> mvn clean install

but when i write command like :

> mvn clover2:instrument clover 2:aggregate clover2:clover

its failing.After building 5 modules its fails and say that some dependency is not found. while when i build it works fine.
I am posting you the pom.xml file on which i am calling these commands

> 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually aggregate doesn't work properly in multi module projects and it's still an open issue for clover team. If I create the reports without using aggregate goal it works fine and also a consolidated report.

so

```
mvn clover2:instrument clover2:aggregate clover2:clover
```

works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with PMD plugin. Try deleting (or renaming) your `~/.m2/repository` directory and re-running the build. Alternatively, delete from your local repository just the jar that contains the class or dependency that is "not found."